# 4x4 post with sleeve but no cap and it rained

Tags: decking

On my new composite deck the 4x4 posts have sleeves and the railing is already installed but I have no put caps on the posts yet. It rained very hard. Should I wait to cap them now? Should I do something to help dry out the posts first?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary.  Your 4x4 posts are PT, right?